# Are private Fonts and Brushes evil?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, gdi+

I have some classes which have Fonts and Brushes as private fields. Something says me this isn't correct practice, and should be avoided, yet I don't know why .... (Darn subconsiousness :-) )

Is this true, and why is it bad practice ?

```
class SomeControl: Panel
{
    private Font titelFont = new Font("Arial", 8.25f, FontStyle.Bold);        
    private SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);


    public SomeControl()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem I see with that is that you hardcoded the font. This could become a problem with translating your program(in particular to Asian languages).

Comment: The only benefit to doing this is if you know you will need to reuse the brush or font continually. If you're just using the objects once (such as to draw onto a bitmap), it's better to create them when you need them and dispose them as soon as you get finished. The overhead of creating and disposing GDI objects is essentially negligible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why it's bad.

When using brushes, you already have static [`Brushes` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brushes.aspx) you may want to reuse instead of creating your own (just like you do with common colors).

For example, instead of creating `whiteBrush`, you may rather use `Brushes.White` directly.

Of course, it gives you only a common set of brushes, so you still need to create your own brush for any other color.

Just remember than fonts and brushes must be **properly disposed**. It means that when using your own fonts and brushes as a property or a field of a class, this class must implement `IDisposable` and properly dispose those fonts and brushes.

Comment: So in my example, would I have to implement IDisposable ? What happens if you don't ? I suspect the Fonts and brushes staying in memory untill GC.Collect() ??

Comment: @Run CMD: *would I have to implement IDisposable ?*: Yes, since at least one field or property of `SomeControl` implements `IDisposable`. *What happens if you don't ?*: the same thing as when you forget a `using` for an `SqlCommand`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Having them private looks fine to me.

But you should either make them static or override the `Dispose` method in `SomeControl` and dispose `titelFont` and `whiteBrush` there.

It is also hard to configure the fonts and brushes in the designer if you don't make them public properties.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky thing is making sure that they get disposed...

But (to make it harder) only if they aren't the inbuilt system brushes etc - since they don't really belong to your form.

If they are diaposed in Dispose() then this is fine. Otherwise it can slowly leak handles. GC *might* catch them, but this is not deterministic.

Comment: Are GDI+ handles more expensive than a few bytes of memory? I know that GDI handles are expensive, but is that the case for GDI+ too?

Comment: Yes.  GDI+ is built on top of GDI, so the expense is relatively the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the font or the brushcolor from outside you have to make it to an public property, if not just let it private.

Don't forget to dispose the brush with the control.
I personaly only set the color of the brush and create the brush itself in on paint.

```
private Color _WhiteBrush = Color.White;
public Color WhiteBrush
{
  get
  {
     return _WhiteBrush;
  }
  set
  {
    _WhiteBrush = value;
    this.Invalidate();
  }
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(this.WhiteBrush))
  {
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(sb, this.ClientRectangle);
  }
}
```